# Erro ao conectar no MySQL com PHP e Docker

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, docker

Estou rodando o Docker e nas configurações passo corretamente as credenciais para a conexão com o MySQL(MariaDB), porém sempre retorna o seguinte erro:

```
http://localhost/error.php?err=Unable%20to%20connect%20to%20MySQL
```

Ou seja: 'Unable to connect to MySQL'.

No arquivo de configurações do Docker estão assim as credenciais:

HOST=localhost
USER=root
PASSWORD=password
DATABASE=db

A senha é diferente da que está sendo informada acima.
Estou usando o Ubuntu e até já criei um outro usuário com os mesmos privilégios do root, porém sempre acontece a mesma coisa.

Quando eu acesso o MySQL pelo DBeaver informando as credenciais ele consegue acessar normalmente e realizar todas as operações, é somente quando carrega o Docker e tentoa abrir no navegador que acontece esses problemas.

Comment: Por favor demostre o código utilizado para ligar ao servidor.

Comment: A aplicação PHP está rodando em outro container - ou no mesmo - ou está rodando do _host_? Inclua a sua compose - pela tag está usando compose -, dockerfile, enfim, o que é necessáiro para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Consegui resolver o meu problema subindo uma imagem do MariaDB junto com o PHP e o HTTPD no Docker, vou adicionar como resposta caso alguém também precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema subindo um container do MariaDB junto com os demais containeres que já estava utilizando e utilizei a ferramenta Portainer para gerenciar os containeres e ver quais ip's e portas direcionar.